# Null Deference flagged by Fortify

Tags: c#, .net, fortify

Fortify is flagging the line with `item.WaitForComplete(0)` as a null dereference. It seems like a false positive to me because "item" was checked for null right above. Any ideas why Fortify is flagging this?

```
if (item != null)
{
    bool isComplete = item.WaitForComplete(0);
    if (isComplete)
    {
        Program.ConsoleWriteLine("{0} - StopIndexingItem for job {1} already stopped removing from list", item._objItemRequest.CaseName, item._objItemRequest.JobId);
        itemListIndexing.RemoveItem(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on `item`...is it an object, what is it?

Comment: Its just a custom c# class. It has the method WaitForComplete() in it. I wanted to keep the code snipped as simple as possible.   If something inside WaitForComplete would trigger the issue, I would think the code would have pinpointed it inside that method. I

Comment: Hm, try checking if isComplete is null as well. It's impossible for it to actually be null, but maybe that's what fortify wants.  Also, "humans > fortify" so you can always 'accept' that flagging :)